# Jquery menu with less code

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery for menu created like:

```
<div class="prof_info1">home</div><div class="prof_info2">info2</div><div class="prof_info3">info3</div>
```

And Jquery code like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".prof_info1").unbind("click").click(function(event) {
$("#main").html('<img src="img/spin.gif" class="spin">');
location.replace("?&id=<?=$id?>")
return false;
});

$(".prof_info2").unbind("click").click(function(event) {
$("#main").html('<img src="img/spin.gif" class="spin">');
$("#main").load('?a=2&id=<?=$id?>');
return false;
});


$(".prof_info3").unbind("click").click(function(event) {
$("#glavni").html('<img src="img/spin.gif" class="spin">');
$("#glavni").load('?a=3&id=<?=$id?>');
return false;
});

});
```

Is there any easier way to do write this Jquery code and make it with less code? 
Something like

```
if click somethind{
...
}elseif{
....}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this solution.

```
<div class="prof_info redirect">
    <a href="?&id=1">home</a>
</div>
<div class="prof_info ajax">
    <a href="?&id=1">info2</a>
</div>
<div class="prof_info ajax">
    <a href="?&id=3">info3</a>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prof_info a").click(function(event) {
        $("#main").html('<img src="img/spin.gif" class="spin">');
        if($(this).parent('.redirect').get(0)){
            location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
        }else{
            $("#main").load($(this).attr('href'));
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="menu_clickable prof_info1" data-element="#main" 
data-load="?&id=<?=$id?>">home</div>


$('.menu_clickable').unbind('click').click(function(){

$(this).attr('data-element').html('<img src="img/spin.gif" class="spin">');
$(this).attr('data-element').load($(this).attr('data-load'));
return false;

});
```

HTH